# How to mask a dataframe given a list of values or indices in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a column 'rel_max' that has a list of all the values of local maxima (if relevant or more useful I also have a column of the indices of these local extrema). I would like to take this list of values or indices and mask the dataframe so that I have a maxima in its correct spot and NaN or 0 for all other values of the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'123': [20.908, 8.743, 8.34, 2.4909],
                 '124': [2, 2.34, 0, 4.1234],
                  '412': [2, 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
                   '516': [5, 20.120, 4.12, 0],
                   '129': [6, 20.10, 3.123123, 0],
                    'rel_max': [[20.908, 6], [8.743,20.123], [8.34,4.12], [4.1234]]},

                 index=['2015-01-10', '2015-02-10', '2015-03-10', '2015-04-10'])
```

This is the dataframe with the relative max values. ^

This is the expected dataframe.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'123': [20.908, 8.743, 8.34, 0],
                 '124': [0, 0, 0, 4.1234],
                  '412': [0, 20.123, 0, 0],
                   '516': [0, 0, 4.12, 0],
                   '129': [6, 0, 0, 0],
                    'rel_max': [[20.908, 6], [8.743,20.123], [8.34,4.12], [4.1234]]},

                 index=['2015-01-10', '2015-02-10', '2015-03-10', '2015-04-10'])
```

Essentially, I am trying to retrieve or pull the dataframe with only the local extrema.

```
               123     124     412   516  129          rel_max
2015-01-10  20.908  0.0000   0.000  0.00    6      [20.908, 6]
2015-02-10   8.743  0.0000  20.123  0.00    0  [8.743, 20.123]
2015-03-10   8.340  0.0000   0.000  4.12    0     [8.34, 4.12]
2015-04-10   0.000  4.1234   0.000  0.00    0         [4.1234]
```

Comment: To clarify: You already know the max values in each row, and you want to set everything in each row except those values to be zero?

Comment: Yes I have already figured out the extrema for each row and I want to mask the df essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use indexing. Firt get the min values and max values, and use numpy and pandas `broadcasting` to create two masks `m1` and `m2`. Then, broadcast again

```
smax = df.rel_max.str[0]
smin = df.rel_max.str[1]

m1 = df == np.broadcast_to(smax.values.reshape(-1,1), df.shape)

m2 = df == np.broadcast_to(smin.values.reshape(-1,1), df.shape)

df[m1 | m2]
```

In more detail, `smax` is a series with the max values and `smin` is a series of the `min` values. `m1` is a data frame of `True`/`False` values. It yields `True` whenever a cell in `df` is equal to one of the values in the broadcasted values. I'd recommend to run each part of the code alone and see the output, it's more intuitive ;)

Output is:

```
            123     124     412     516     129 rel_max
2015-01-10  20.908  0.0000  0.000   0.00    6   [20.908, 6]
2015-02-10  8.743   0.0000  20.123  0.00    0   [8.743, 20.123]
2015-03-10  8.340   0.0000  0.000   4.12    0   [8.34, 4.12]
2015-04-10  0.000   4.1234  0.000   0.00    0   [4.1234]
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is happening in the last 3 lines?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :-1].where(df.apply(lambda x: x[:-1].isin(x.iloc[-1]), axis=1), 0), 
           df.iloc[:, -1]], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
               123     124     412   516  129          rel_max
2015-01-10  20.908  0.0000   0.000  0.00  6.0      [20.908, 6]
2015-02-10   8.743  0.0000  20.123  0.00  0.0  [8.743, 20.123]
2015-03-10   8.340  0.0000   0.000  4.12  0.0     [8.34, 4.12]
2015-04-10   0.000  4.1234   0.000  0.00  0.0         [4.1234]
```